# Qt delete current ListWidgetItem causes crash

Tags: c++, qt

I have 3 Lists, an `idList`, a `filmList` and a `songList`. When deleting or adding an item from the `QListWidget` it should also be deleted in two of those lists (in `idList` + `filmList` or `songList`). However, that's not the problem. The problem is that when I delete exactly 8 items from the list, the program crashes.

Whats wrong?

```
connect( removeButton, SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SLOT( remove() ) );

//My remove function
void MainWindow::remove()
{
    if( list->currentRow() != -1 ){
        const unsigned int row = list->currentRow();
        if( dm->remove( categoryBox->currentText(), idList.at( row ) ) )
        {
            idList.removeAt( row );

            //Remove from specific list
            if( currentCategory() == cFilm )
                filmList.removeAt( row );
            else if( currentCategory() == cSong )
                songList.removeAt( row );
            else if( currentCategory() == cApp )
                ;

            delete list->takeItem(row);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the variable type for dm that you call remove for?

Comment: @Merlin069 It's a self created class. It just removes items from my SQL Database

Comment: You're using Qt classes correctly. Check for valid `removeAt` arguments -  index may be out of bounds. Run the app under debugger to find out which line causes the crash.

Comment: I just imported the whole project to windows and it works perfectly. I have this problem only under linux although it works with the other two classes